# XML display document tree on browser

Tags: python, xml, rest

[image: Screenshot]

Hello everyone. I think this is a newbie question.

How would I be able to have my xml printed using python, in the same way as the browser screenshot shows?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` configured as a `xml` parser

Comment: @Drako I converted json to xml through `dicttoxml` and then returned the xml as response. It is only printing the values and not the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom

parent_file_path = 'samplexml.xml'
parent_tree = ET.parse(parent_file_path)
parent = parent_tree.getroot()
xmlstr = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(parent)).toprettyxml()
print xmlstr
```